# SQL inner join with timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables currently.

**Table 1 : Sales**

```
saleId(int), saleTime(datetime), deviceId(varchar)
```

This table simply keeps track of sales, what time they occurred, and on what device they were completed.

**Table 2 : SaleColor**

```
deviceId, color(varchar), timeDetected(datetime), timeRemoved(datetime), isActive(bit)
```

This table keeps track of what  color item is being sold on each device and each device can only sell one color at a time. So for example, YELLOW may be sold between 3/10/20 00:00:00 and 3/10/20 10:15:00 for DEVICE1. timeDetected represents the time a color began being sold, timeRemoved is the time it stopped being sold. If the item is still being sold, timeRemoved = null and isActive = 1.

**My Goal**
I need to be able to pull all transactions that occurred in a time frame for a single device and the color of the item that was sold. So the end results would look like...

```
device, saleid, saleTime, color
```

I have been using the following to pull the color for a specific timestamp, but I can't seem to work this into my query to pull all of the transactions and match them with the correct background for that time.

```
select color
from SaleColor
where
(
    (timedetected < '3/10/20 08:15:00' and timeremoved > '3/10/20 08:15:00')
    or (timedetected < '3/10/20 08:15:00' and timeremoved is null)
)
and deviceId = 'DEVICE1'
```

If I nest the above statement into my select statement for the transactions, it sets the same color for each transaction.

Could someone help me get these two queries setup in a way that actually works?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help us help you.

Comment: To be honest this sounds like the real problem is that the design is not well normalized. You have a parent/child between these tables but the join sounds rather loosey goosey instead of precise. It sounds like you have to use oddball time ranges to join them instead of something solid like an order number.

Comment: Sean's right, but assuming you can't do anything about the schema here, how does the `saleTime` column in `Sales` relate to the `timeDetected` and `timeRemoved` columns in `SaleColor`?

Comment: Can't you just JOIN `ON s.deviceId = sc.deviceId AND s.saleTime >= sc.timeDetected AND (sc.timeDetected IS NULL OR s.saleTime <= sc.timeDetected)`? *(In this scenario `s` is `Sales` and `sc` is `SaleColor`)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner join to filter the corresponding color:

```
select a.device, a.saleid, a.saleTime, b.color
from Sales a 
inner join SaleColor b
ON b.timedetected <= a.saletime and ISNULL(b.timeremoved,'01Jan2100') >= a.saletime
   and a.deviceId = b.deviceID 
   --and a.deviceId = 'DEVICE1'
```

I have simplified the condition you had on the question. You can adjust the ON condition to suit your needs.

Comment: This is what did the job. I'm not strong with SQL so I wasn't 100% sure how to correctly format the join with multiple matches. I edited yours a bit and it is now grabbing me the correct info. I appreciate it!